# emacs lisp listing files with glob expansion

Tags: lisp, elisp

Are there any library or function that performs a bash-like glob expansion for emacs lisp?

For example:

```
(directory-files-glob "~/Desktop/*")
> ("/home/user/Desktop/file1" "/home/user/Desktop/file2")
```

If there isn't such a function are there any hint/suggestion on how to implement it?

EDIT:

I've found in the [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Contents-of-Directories.html#Contents-of-Directories) also an useful function that does quite exactly this:

> file-expand-wildcards: 
>   This function expands the wildcard pattern pattern, returning a list of file names that match it.

Comment: Thanks - file-expand-wildcards is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check out the documentation for [`directory-files`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Contents-of-Directories.html#Contents-of-Directories):

```
(directory-files "~/Desktop" nil ".")
```

*Note:* The third argument is a regular expression - not globbing.

It is straight forward to turn globbing patterns into regular expressions.  [eshell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html) comes with a translation package which you can use:

```
(require 'em-glob)
(defun directory-files-glob (path)
   (directory-files (file-name-directory path) 
                    nil 
                    (eshell-glob-regexp (file-name-nondirectory path))))
```

And, if you want full exposure to eshell's globbing (with directories), there's probably a way to get that.  The above assumes that the globbing part is in the non-directory portion of the path.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation and the further ideas!

Answer (score 24):

Not sure why this was overlooked maybe it was not in emacs in 2010 but in a current emacs at least there is function [file-expand-wildcards](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Contents-of-Directories.html#Contents-of-Directories)

```
(file-expand-wildcards "~/Desktop/*")
```

which does exactly what you want to do..

Comment: Oh saw the edit of the Q which already includes this, but since I overlooked it here I'll leave my answer anyway

Answer (score 5):

Package [`f`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) adds a huge amount of file and filepath manipulation functions under a consistent naming scheme. It has a function [`f-glob`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-glob-pattern-optional-path) that does exactly that:

```
(f-glob "~/doc/*.org") ; returns a list of files ending with ".org"
(f-glob "*.org" "~/doc/") ; they all behave the same
(f-glob "*.org" "~/doc")
```